# Awk to print lines between first pattern and second pattern where second pattern occurs above and below the first pattern

Tags: awk

I'm trying to print all the lines including the first match until the first occurrence of second match where second match occurs above and below the first match.

The file I have contains records which are separated by empty lines like below,

```
host      host1  
key1      value  
key2      value  
key3      value  

host      host2  
key1      value  
key2      value  
key3      value  
key4      value  
key5      value  

host      host3  
key1      value  
key2      **aaaa**  
key3      value  

host      host3  
key1      value  
key2      value
```

let's say my search pattern is "aaaa". I want to print lines above the first match to "aaaa" until the empty line, and also the lines below the first match to "aaaa" until the empty line. So the search should output:

```
host      host3  
key1      value  
key2      aaaa  
key3      value
```

I cannot use grep since each record will contain a different number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= '/aaaa/' file
host      host3
key1      value
key2      **aaaa**
key3      value
```

Comment: Thanks that works.... how would i add a empty line if between records if there is more than one match?

Comment: One more thing how can i make RS case insensitive?

Comment: To print a blank line between output records add `-v ORS='\n\n'` and since the RS is empty it IS case insensitive since there's no case involved.

Comment: If you mean how to make the regexp comparison case-insensitive, that's `tolower($0) ~ /aaaa/` or set `IGNORECASE=1` in GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Finally is there a config file where we can set the default ORS value and IGNORECASE

Comment: No there isn't, just set them in the BEGIN section of the script, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; IGNORECASE=1} /aaaa/' file`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. For anyone looking for a similar solution, you can use the following awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n\n"; FS="\n"; } /aaaa/  {print}' << inputfile
```

Comment: While that will produce the output you expect, it's unnecessarily gawk-specific due to multi-char RS, using unnecessary input redirection, setting FS for no reason at all, and redundantly specifying the default behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39783262/1745001 for the right approach.